# Azure Users Password Strength Check

Tags: azure, passwords, password-strength

i'm looking for any Possible way to check my Azure Domain Users Passwords Strength (Powershell Script or on Admin Center ) .

i'm not sure if that possible with Azure

Anyone has something know Something How To ??

Thanks

i have searched but i just founded Information about On-Premsis Environment .

Answer (score 1):

> i'm looking for any Possible way to check my Azure Domain Users Passwords Strength (Powershell Script or on Admin Center ) .

`Azure AD` doesn't provide a built-in way to directly check the current strength of `Azure AD` users' passwords, but you can verify that `Azure AD` user password policy options are defined in `Azure AD` on [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#microsoft-entra-password-policies). You can rely on Azure's password policies and protection features to ensure strong password practices among your users.

You can also set a custom password policy for all Azure AD users by following the steps below.

**Navigate to the [Microsoft Admin Center](https://entra.microsoft.com/) > Protection > Authentication Methods > Password Protection** using the required role, such as [User Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference#user-administrator).

[image]

In a hybrid environment, you can deploy `Microsoft Password Protection` to both on-premises and cloud environments. The same global and custom banned password lists are used for both cloud and on-premises password change requests, follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-password-ban-bad-on-premises-deploy)  about hybrid environment

Reference: [What is the default Azure AD password policy?](https://ourcloudnetwork.com/how-to-create-a-password-policy-in-azure-active-directory/)